# 408 request timeout error occurred between ELB and EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

It is a question about AWS.

The following error occurred between ELB and EC2(nginx).

- ELB

  `HTTP 504: Gateway Timeout`
- EC2(nginx)

  `HTTP Error 408 Request timeout`

Have someone discovered the same phenomenon? and know the cause?

Comment: did you open all the required ports on ELB and EC2. provide screen-shot of your security group with the ports.

Comment: Sorry, cannot upload security group screenshot.
and yes, all required port is open.

Comment: Same issue, did you happen to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting 408 in nginx error.log ? If yes, then it has nothing to do with ELB because it shows that request is going from ELB to nginx; and nginx itself is giving "Request timeout".. It is an application issue..Your application is not able to process the request.

One way to test would be to expose EC2 to public i.e. associate an Elastic IP address to EC2 and try to connect to it directly i.e. removing ELB from picture to be double sure.

Comment: Sorry, the response slowed down.

Answer is yes.
Basically works normally, but it happens occasionally.

Since log of uwsgi is not left, It is thought that trouble occurred in transmission of from ELB to nginx.
The gateway timeout of ELB is 120s, request timeout set in nginx is also 120s.
Idle timeout setting of ELB is 3600s.